# Sort value intoarray

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql

I have a question in PLSQL ORACLE
I got an table of object and in this table I collect these type of object:

```
    OBJECTS_TABLE
object1 -> ID: 1 VALUE: a
object2 -> ID: 2 VALUE: b
object3 -> ID: 3 VALUE: c
object4 -> ID: 1 VALUE: d
```

instead of this I want to sort it and got

```
    OBJECTS_TABLE
object1 -> ID: 1 VALUE: a,d
object2 -> ID: 2 VALUE: b
object3 -> ID: 3 VALUE: c
```

Thanks for helping .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly. You wish to transform a table of non-distinct IDs and associated Values to a table of distinct IDs and a column containing comma-separated values.

If I understand you correctly then I would basically write up a new table. And make a procedure that loops through the first table:

```
BEGIN
  FOR cursor IN cursor_through_original_table
    LOOP
    BEGIN
      SELECT value
        INTO temp_variable
        FROM new_table
       WHERE id = cursor.id;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN no_data_found THEN
        temp_variable := NULL;
    END;
    IF temp_variable IS NOT NULL THEN
      UPDATE new_table
         SET value = temp_variable || ', ' || cursor.value
       WHERE id = cursor.id;
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO new_table (id, value)
      VALUES (cursor.id, cursor.value);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

This is not code for you to copy-paste, wrote it w/o testing or even rereading it so it's bound to have errors, and its also missing declarations. But its to get my point across about how to do it.

I hope it fits your needs and you get whatever you are working on working.

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped if you posted table description, so I'll just guess that this (`objects_table` CTE) is what you have and what you'd want to get (line #8 onward):

```
SQL> with objects_table (id, value) as
  2    (Select 1, 'a' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'b' from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'c' from dual union all
  5     select 1, 'd' from dual
  6    )
  7  -- The following SELECT might be what you are looking for
  8  select id, listagg(value, ',') within group (order by value) value
  9  from objects_table
 10  group by id
 11  order by id;

        ID VALUE
---------- --------------------
         1 a,d
         2 b
         3 c

SQL>
```